# Page level access in Google sites

Tags: google-sites

IS there are feature for providing page level access in [Google sites](http://sites.google.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is UNFORTUNATELY :( not released yet as mentionned by a Google employee:

> Hi everyone,
>
> As I've posted before, we are working on this and will hopefully have it out soon. Thanks to everyone for your patience and understanding while we finish some of our other areas and work to make this product the best it can be.
>
> Implementing features like this take time to perfect, especially when working on such a large scale. If it was as easy as just flipping a switch the feature would be out by now. We have to make sure that it works correctly and does so on the large scale with which we find ourselves operating. I again thank you for your patience and understanding while we work on this.
>
> Because this thread is devolving from positive postings about why Page Level Permissions are requested into negative ones about the time it's taking, I'm closing it down. We want this community to remain positive, and while we do understand that there are frustrations about how long it can take for a feature to come out, posting increasingly negative and bitter comments does no one any good. Please know that we are in the process of getting this feature out and hope to have it out soon.
>
> Thank you everyone for taking the time to post in here.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=0af2865116e1c041&hl=en&start=40